# Uploading images to Google Cloud Platform with a buffer creates blank image

Tags: image, file-upload, google-cloud-platform, pipe, buffer

I did successfully upload something (an image.jpg) to google cloud platform using a buffer. However, when I follow the link to the image itself, it leads to a blank screen with a small white square in the middle which I assume is a placeholder for no image.

```
    const buffer = file.buffer.toString('utf-8');
    const uploadFile = bucket.file(file.name);

    const stream = uploadFile.createWriteStream({
      metadata: { contentType: file.mimeType }
    });

    stream.pipe(stream)
    .on('error', err => console.log('upload failed', err))
    .on('finish', () => console.log('upload success', file.name))
    .end(new Buffer(buffer, 'binary'));

    // console.log(`File uploaded succesfully (${file})`);
    return // the full url which is does successfully
```

I can't figure out why my buffer isn't getting parsed back into an image after being uploaded? It is as if a string was uploaded as a file, which is meaningless.

I have also tried this version which has the same result.

```
return await bucket
.file(file.urlName)
.save(buffer, {
  metadata: { contentType: file.mime }
})
.then(res => {
  console.log('success', res);
  return this.getPublicUrl(file.urlName);
})
.catch(err => console.log('error', err));
```

Comment: stream.pipe(stream) seems a bit suspicious. You're taking a stream and piping to itself.

Comment: I thought it was a little odd. It "worked" since it uploaded but what is there is not what I uploaded. I got this information from here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2334

Comment: That code didn't pipe to itself. It just created the stream and listened to the different events

Answer (score 1):

This version worked

```
return await bucket
.file(file.urlName)
.save(file.buffer, {
  metadata: { contentType: file.mime }
})
.then(res => {
  console.log('success', res);
  return this.getPublicUrl(file.urlName);
})
.catch(err => console.log('error', err));
```

provided that the buffer was not stringed, unlike the requirement from other examples.